# Generate a random number for each day

Tags: r, random

I'm looking a way to generate a random number for a day and that this random number remains stable for the entire day. The next day, the code will generate another random number and so on.

I precise that I don't need to assign the same random number for the same day each year.

The actual code :

```
# Data
MyMax <- 45
MyValues <- paste0("The video of the day is : video_", seq(1:MyMax))

# Random generator
MyRandomNumber <- sample(1:MyMax, 1)

# Output
print(MyValues[MyRandomNumber])
```

Expected output :

-> Each time that I use the code the December 16, 2017 :

```
[1] "The video of the day is : video_35"
[1] "The video of the day is : video_35"
```

-> Each time that I use the code the December 17, 2017 :

```
[1] "The video of the day is : video_48"
[1] "The video of the day is : video_48"
```

-> Each time that I use the code the December 16, 2018 :

```
[1] "The video of the day is : video_12"
[1] "The video of the day is : video_12"
```

Comment: Do you have a vector of days? A dataframe of days? Do you have datetime values?

Comment: You're looking for something so better to change it rather than delete it! :-) Show us how your data looks like when you start (vector? dataset?) and how you want it to look in the end.

Comment: Use `set.seed()` to start the random number generator at a predictable point.

Comment: Should the random number be the same for the same day each year? ie: use the same random number for Jan-01 every year, or a new random number every time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# specify maximun random number (minimum is 1)
MyMax <- 100

# this will make sure randomisation remains stable at each day
set.seed(as.numeric(Sys.Date()))

# show the randomised value
paste0("The video of the day is : video_", sample(1:MyMax, 1))

# [1] "The video of the day is : video_79"
```

No matter how many times you run this code today, you'll always get the same output. Tomorrow it will change and will remain stable for the whole day, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The solution I found with the help of above comments.

```
# Data
MyMax <- 45
MyValues <- paste0("The video of the day is : video_", seq(1:MyMax))

# Random generator
set.seed(as.numeric(Sys.Date()))
MyRandomNumber <- sample(1:MyMax, 1)

# Output
print(MyValues[MyRandomNumber])
```

Comment: `sample` can sample directly from your vector, so you shouldn't need `MyRandomNumber` at all: `sample(MyValues,1)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

This should generate a random number for each day.

```
library(tidyverse)

dayYear <- as.Date(Sys.Date(),format='%d/%m/%Y') %>% lubridate::yday() %>% integer()
set.seed(dayYear)
randNum <- rnorm(1)
```